# How to create an impulse train .wav with sox or other linux command line tools

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, signal-processing, sox

I need a .wav file with 44100Hz sample rate, that contains a positive 1-sample impulse every 2 seconds, repeated for about 1 minute.

I've not yet found an elegant way to do this with linux command line tools, like sox, ffmpeg,... but am working on it.

Comment: What about GNU Octave with some [audio plugin](http://octave.sourceforge.net/audio/index.html)?

Comment: I run linux in a proot chroot on android, so a SoX/ffmpeg solution would suit me better. Anyway, the whole question is not that relevant anymore as it was when I posted.

Comment: Is the answer satisfactory for you?

Answer (score 3):

It can be easily done with sox:

```
sox -b 16 -Dr 44100 -n out.wav synth 1s square pad 88199s repeat 30
```

The mindset is following:

`-b 16` set the bit-depth to 16 bits

`-Dr 44100` use a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz and do not add any dithering noise

`-n out.wav` input file is null and the output file is out.wav

`synth 1s square` synthesize one sample of a square wave (32768)

`pad 88199s` pad with zeros to reach 2 seconds of duration

`repeat 30` repeat 30 times to reach 1 minute of a pulse train